# How to replace loop with "if" and "elif" but without "else" by list comprehension

Tags: python

I am trying to use list comprehension for below code

```
# Input
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```
# Using for loop
ans = []

for value in values:
    if value == 1:
        ans.append(value + value)
    elif value == 4:
        ans.append(value * value)

print(f"Ans: {ans}")
```

```
# Using list comprehension

ans = [
    (value + value) 
    if value == 1
    else (value * value) if value == 4 
    for value in values
]

print(f"Ans: {ans}")
```

But getting error for list comprehension as below:

> SyntaxError: expected 'else' after 'if' expression

I tried defining `else` part like below, but it did not work:

```
else pass
else continue
```

The output should be `[2, 16]`. Other values are skipped.

What I am missing?

Comment: What should be in the result list if the value is neither 1 nor 4?

Comment: There is no reason to use a list comprehension for this.

Comment: `ans = [value + value if value==1 else value*value for value in values if value in [1,4]]` should do the trick, but it's complicated so I would consider doing it the more traditional route. The reason your attempt wasn't working is because using `if/else` as a ternary operator requires an `else`. You have chained two ternary operators together and the last one doesn't terminate with an `else`. The proper form is:  `<value> if <condition> else (<value> if <condition> else <some other value>)`. However, using that form would cause you to add <someothervalue> to your `ans` list.

Comment: `ans = [value + value if value==1 else value * value for value in values if value in {1,4}]`

But remember readable code is better than unreadable fancy code

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you're missing. The second `if` has no `else`. It's optional in an `if` statement, but not in a ternary expression, since an expression has to have a value.

Comment: Why in the world would you turn that loop into a list comprehension? Are you trying to win an obfuscated Python contest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is a small example of something more complicated, but as it is it is fairly easy to create a comprehension like:

```py
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ans = [
    value + value if value == 1 else value * value
    for value in values
    if value in [1,4]
]
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your missing the last else of the second tertiary operation.  The `a if condition else b` structure always needs both the `if` and the `else`.  Since you have two of those the structure is equivalent to :

```
a if condition1 else (b if condition2 else c)
```

in your specific case:

```
ans = [ (value + value) if value == 1 
        else
        (value * value) if value == 4 
        else
        value
        for value in values
      ]
```